# Batch async requests in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I've seen many answers here on Stackoverflow recommending people to handle multiple async calls using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). I do think that Promise.all() helps when the calls are made to do a similar job, but I have a few issues with this approach:

1. If the Promises take different time to resolve the tasks;
2. If you can start doing work with the tasks as they get. Promise.all waits the Promises to be resolved (or rejected) to start executing the callback. This is the main con for this approach in my opinion.

Is there a different approach?

In React (using hooks), for example, we can do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setValue1(await fetch(url1));
});

useEffect(() => {
  setValue2(await fetch(url2));
});
```

But this doesn't look right to me... maybe this is "correct", though.

Anyway, my reason to post this is that I would really appreciate some good indication on how to approach async calls that handle different logic.

Thanks.

Comment: You're right to question Promise.all()'s use when you can do things immediately with each Promise's resolved data, but things become more complex when you depend on the success of many async calls. For example, you may not be able to render a view with partial data. You need all of it. Promise.all() is nice for that, or when one fails, you need to handle an error scenario immediately. It's definitely not a replacement for individual Promises, as arrays don't replace scalars. It's just nice to have, as arrays are nice to have too.

Comment: Very interesting comment, Rafael. It makes a lot of sense to me what you said